# Resizing the carousel item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the following code to create carousel,

```
   <section id="slider">
    <div id="landing-page-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active carsi">
          <img class="landing-pg-image" src="image/1.png" alt="profile">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item carsi">
          <img class="landing-pg-image" src="image/2.png" alt="profile">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item carsi">
          <img class="landing-pg-image" src="image/3.png" alt="profile">
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#landing-page-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#landing-page-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

I would like to have the carousel to occupy only 70% of the screen hence I use the following rule,

```
.carsi{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

Unfortunately, this has no effect on the carousel item. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.when you use it in this way, you can change the image height proportionally with the carousel item.

```
.carousel .item {
  width:100%;
  height: 70%;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 70%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```